# BackgroundWorker in ASP.NET page doesn't work as expected: not async and isBusy is always false

Tags: c#, asp.net, backgroundworker

I'm pretty new on ASP.NET but I've already used BackgroundWorkers on desktop applications.

This time I've created a simple ASP page that shows a button. When it's clicked, a 5 second operation is called and I want to set a graphical "loading" state. For example, I simply want to disable that button.

I tried this way:

```
private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
// ...
protected void confirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (selectedAccount == null || worker.IsBusy) return;

    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false; 
    worker.DoWork += (ss, ee) => {
        // the operation
        sync.StartOperation(selectedAccount);
    };

    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        // Operation finished, update the GUI

        Report finalReport = sync.GetFinalReport();
        if (finalReport.HasErrors())
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("Error");
        }
        else
        {
            ShowSuccessMessage("Completed");
        }

        SetLoadingState(false);
    };

    // before starting the worker, set a "loading" status ( => disable the button)
    SetLoadingState(true);
    // then start!
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

There are two problems here:

- The GUI is not updated to the "loading" state (aka button doesn't get disabled). Seems like the operation is not really "async"...
- Since I can still press the button during the operation, I tried to rely on the `worker.isBusy` value... but this property **is always false**, even if the operation is clearly running.

For the record, the last part where RunWorkerCompleted should be called works. The GUI is correctly updated with error or success messages.

What's wrong with that? Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer, but I would recommend looking into the async/await pattern, which makes code like this much simpler. That said, does the button get disabled if you put a breakpoint after the SetLoadingState(false) and before the worker starts to run?

Comment: Yes, the button gets disabled if I put a breakpoint.
Anyway, I'll try with the async/await pattern... but does this mean that the BackgroundWorker is not suitable for this job?

Comment: It is suitable, but async/await is supposed to do the same thing as the background worker in an easier to follow way. You could test the worker more by putting a Thread.Sleep(5000) somewhere in the DoWork to make sure that the background process actually takes some time.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is not suitable for ASP.NET. You'd better take a look at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx